# Firebird - Converting stored integer to time equivalent

Tags: sql, firebird, flamerobin

I am currently working on a Firebird database which stores slots for a time (like appointments).  In the data the timeslot is stored in an Integer format but is not the slot time.

Example:
Slot Time: 11am
Database Value: 660

The database value is represented as the number of minutes since midnight.  So 11am is 660 minutes from midnight. Or 12noon is 720

**Question** How, in Firebird, can a convert this 660 to display as 1100 (still an integer) or 540 as 900 (basically 9am)?

Comment: Why not just use a `TIME` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have stored into database is minutes since start of the day. So you just divide with 60 to get hours. Keep in mind that in SQL if both arguments of the division are integers you'll get integer as an answer, not decimal! Something like following should work for you (assuming the number of minutes is stored to `timeslot` field):

```
SELECT 
 cast(timeslot / 60 as varchar(2)) || 
   case
     when mod(timeslot, 60) < 10 then '0'|| mod(timeslot, 60)
     else mod(timeslot, 60)
   end
FROM t
```

This should give you `1130` for 11:30 am, not `1150` (11,5 hours).

Also see the [DATEADD](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-dateadd.html) function.

Answer (score 2):

First off I'd store it in the database as a `TIME` column instead of a number of minutes. Note that on a technical level Firebird stores `TIME` as the number of 100 microseconds since midnight. However if you really want to store as number of minutes, then you can use:

From minutes to `TIME` using [`DATEADD`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-dateadd.html):

```
DATEADD(x MINUTE TO TIME'00:00')
```

Time to minutes using [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-datediff.html):

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE FROM TIME'00:00' TO y)
```

So:

```
SELECT 
  DATEADD(660 MINUTE TO TIME'00:00'), 
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE FROM TIME'00:00' TO TIME'11:00') 
FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Will return: `11:00:00.000, 660`